# Regex match everything between word and comma

Tags: regex

I have example sting

```
   Я, Вагапова Варвара Сергеевна, 29.10.1990 года
```

I need to extract everything between `Я,` and second comma `,` so result should be `Вагапова Варвара Сергеевна`

I wrote an expression

```
(?<=Я, )(.*)(?=,)
```

But it is captures more [image]

Comment: It could be like this using a negated character class `(?<=Я, )[^,]+(?=,)` https://regex101.com/r/pl3Mwz/1

Comment: In general, `(?<=left).*?(?=right)`